# How to access record type when column names are ambiguous?

Tags: postgresql

I have this function where I store the result of a query in a `RECORD` type variable.

The problem is that the two tables of my query have one column with the same name ("description"), and I don't know how I can distinguish these two using my `RECORD` variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_x(_id BIGINT)
RETURNS TEXT AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    l_row RECORD;
    l_tableADescription TEXT;
    l_tableBDescription TEXT;

BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO l_row
    FROM tableA a
    JOIN tableB b ON (a.idA = b.idA)
    WHERE e.idA = _id;

    -- problem is here
    l_tableADescription = l_row.tableA.description;
    l_tableBDescription = l_row.tableB.description;

    -- do other stuff

    RETURN '';

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Using `AS` in the `SELECT` clause is not an option because these two tables have a large number of columns.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.4

Comment: `AS` and `*` are not mutually exclusive: `SELECT a.desc AS a_desc, * FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

If the column names are not unique, I don't know of any way around naming the variables when you enter the query. i.e.:

```
SELECT a.description AS t1Desc, b.description AS t2Desc, *
INTO row
FROM tableA a 
JOIN tableB b ON (a.idA = b.idB);
```

Then to access them individually from the RECORD variable:

```
tableADescription_1 = row.t1Desc;
tableBDescription_1 = row.t2Desc;
```

Use the names as specified in the query, not the original column names from the table.

That's what we used in a project where we had two tables in a join with a common name.